# How can I remove same words in both columns? Duplicates in both rows

Tags: pandas

I would like to delete Alabama from both colums

**State**  --------------------- **RegionName**

Alabama   ---------------------   Alabama

Alabama  ---------------------    Auburn

Alabama   ---------------------   Florence

so the outcome would be:

**State**  --------------------- **RegionName**

Alabama  ---------------------    Auburn

Alabama   ---------------------   Florence

I tried through looping but it is not working:

```
   if df['RegionName'].iloc[i] == df['State'].iloc[i]:
       df.RegionName.drop(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give what you want:

```
new_df=df[df['RegionName'] != df['State']]
```